# How to use this descriptor in object Typescript?

Tags: typescript, typescript2.0

I have an interface:

```
export interface DisabledFormFields {
  active: number,
  functions: {
    get?($event: any): string;
    set?($event: any): void;
  }
}
```

Then I create object based on this intreface:

```
var instance = {
    active: 0,
    set(event) {
       this.active = event.index;
    },
    get(event) {
       return "-";
    },
}
```

Using this:

```
instance.set({index: 0});
instance.get({});
```

Why I can not get access to property `active` using `this` descriptor inside method of object?

Comment: What error do you get? The first thing I see is that the interface and the object do not match. (functions sub-object is missing)

Comment: Why have you tagged this with two different version of TypeScript?

Comment: There are no any errors

Comment: Just this is not available in object

Comment: Your code example isn't sufficient to show a problem - the code works for me.

Comment: Can you reproduce here? https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your (slightly changed) object:

```
var instance: Disable = {
    active: 0,
    set(event: any) {
        this.active = event.index;
    },
    get(event: any) {
        event;// doing nothing but dealing with the noUnusedParameteres
        return "-";
    },
}
```

Could have this interface:

```
interface Disable {
    active: number;
    set?(event: any): void; // not necessarily optional
    get?(event: any): string;// idem
}
```

If the set and get are optional, it's necessary to use a type guard to see if they are defined:

```
if(instance.set) {
    instance.set({index: 1});// it is defined in this block
}
```

In your original interface you had this inner object...

```
functions: {
    get?($event: any): string;
    set?($event: any): void;
}
```

That you had not included in your object. The object does not implement the interface also because the structure is different and it does not have annotation in the var declaration. You have to change the interface or your object.

Comment: I really dont understand your solution, for me it is the same that I posted. It does notwork inside object: `this.active = event.index;`

Comment: It looks the same because is the same(therefore the slightly changed). It just gives some ideas why your interface has no use in this case. Try removing the interface, don't declare the type, just use the object as you've defined. If it give some compilation error, update the question with the code number of the error, like "TS1234 something gone wrong"

Comment: You can try here, it does not work: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/

Comment: @Oleg it works. This solution is correct. Try to read it again. Your interface and you var doesn't match.

Answer (score 1):

I've used the playground and tried this

```
var instance = {
    active: 0,
    set(event) {
        this.active = event.index;
    },
    get(event) {
        return "<h1>-</h1>";
    },
}

instance.set({index: 0});
instance.get({});

document.writeln(instance.get({}));
```

It transpiled to this:

```
var instance = {
    active: 0,
    set: function (event) {
        this.active = event.index;
    },
    get: function (event) {
        return "<h1>-</h1>";
    },
};
instance.set({ index: 0 });
instance.get({});
document.writeln(instance.get({}));
```

And when clicked on run it opened a new tab in my browser with this:

## -

Comment: the playground probably did not have all the strict type check on because it did not refused the _event_ parameters without the type annotation.